How to Ensure Smooth Navigation to LoginPage and Proper TabBar Functionality in MAUI App
I'm developing a .NET MAUI application where I need the following functionality:
Navigate to LoginPage on Each App Start: Every time user starts the app, they should take to the LoginPage regardless of any prior navigation history.
Correct TabBar Functionality: After logging in, the TabBar should work correctly, showing the right content for each tab
Problem:
To achieve the first requirement, I'm setting the MainPage to a new instance of AppShell after login. However, this approach causes a couple of issues:
White Screen Issue: After logging in for the first time, a white screen appears briefly before navigating to the desired page. Subsequent Navigation Flickers: During further navigation, brief white flashes are degrading the user experience.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MobileControlerMAUI.Views"
       x:Class="MobileControlerMAUI.AppShell"
       Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <Page.Behaviors>
        <mct:StatusBarBehavior x:Name="statusBar" StatusBarColor="Black" StatusBarStyle="LightContent"/>
    </Page.Behaviors>

    <Shell.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar">
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="#1a237e" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="#FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="#FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#B0BEC5" />
        </Style>
    </Shell.Resources>

    <TabBar x:Name="MainTabBar">
        <Tab x:Name="NotificationTab" Icon="notification_icon.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:NotificationPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab x:Name="HomeTab" Icon="home_icon.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>

[RelayCommand]
private async Task Login()
{
    try
    {
        // Authentication

        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Success", "Success", "OK")

        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NotificationPage));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", $"{ex.Message}", "ОК");
    }
}

What I've Tried:
Setting MainPage to a new instance of AppShell: This ensures the navigation stack is reset, but causes the white screen issue.
Using a loading indicator and delay: Attempted to smooth out the transition, but didn't fully resolve the white screen issue.
What I Need:
I want to ensure that every time the app starts, it navigates to the LoginPage and the TabBar functions correctly without displaying a white screen or causing flickers during navigation. How can I achieve this in a MAUI application?

In my test, the white screen only appear when I set new value for App.Current.MainPage. The Shell.Current.GoToAsync will not cause it.

Your default page should be the LoginPage so you can set <ShellItem Route="login">     <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" /> </ShellItem> outside of the MainTabBar like mentioned in this solution.
